# pull dynamic cell range addres from a cell on another sheet created using a formula and use it in another formula

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I am using this formula to create a cell range dynamically:

```
=concat("'180Day Runners'!A3:A" , COUNTA(A:A)) depending on the number of rows the countA finds the result is '180Day Runners'!A3:A389
```

I would like to pull this result into another sheet and use it in a formula but I am not able to get the syntax correct in the nested formula.

```
=arrayformula(transpose(ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY('Raw Run Data'!A:O,"SELECT F,G, max(J) WHERE G='5K' AND M = 7 AND ( F=1 "& concatenate(ARRAYFORMULA( " OR F=" & **'180Day Runners'!A4:A388** )) &" ) GROUP BY F, G pivot O ",1)),1,false))))
```

I would like to replace the `'180Day Runners'!A4:A388` with the result of the first formula but I am unable to get the syntax correct. I have tried `INDIRECT('180Day Runners'!B2)` but this just produces a parse error with no explanation.

here is a link to a working copy

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12SLmsLOSfCOHt9e1C065LPjrXUP3n1qIwsAZFzphN8U/edit?usp=sharing

Cell C3 is where the main formula is situated on the 5K progress sheet

Comment: can you share your sample sheet.

Comment: here is a link to a copy of the sheets https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12SLmsLOSfCOHt9e1C065LPjrXUP3n1qIwsAZFzphN8U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Cell C3 is where the main formula is on the 5K Progress sheet

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SORT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY('Raw Run Data'!A:O,
 "select F,G,max(J) 
  where G ='5K' 
    and M = 7 
    and F matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, '180Day Runners'!A4:A)&"|1'  
  group by F,G pivot O", 1)), 1, 0)))
```

(untested because your sheet can't be copied)

or perhaps:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SORT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TO_TEXT('Raw Run Data'!A:O),
 "select Col6,Col7,max(Col10) 
  where Col7 ='5K' 
    and Col13 = '7' 
    and Col6 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, '180Day Runners'!A4:A)&"|1'  
  group by Col6,Col7 pivot Col15", 1)), 1, 0)))
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to have a look. I'm not sure why the option to prevent a copy was ticked but i have unticked it now. Unfortunately your suggestion doesn't currently work but i will investigate using MATCHES as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying a combination of syntax layouts and have managed to get the formula functioning. The final formula is as follows. a nested indirect function did work in the end.
=arrayformula(transpose(ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY('Raw Run Data'!A:O,"SELECT F,G, max(J) WHERE G='5K' AND M = 7 AND ( F=1 "& concatenate(ARRAYFORMULA( " OR F=" & **indirect('180Day Runners'!B2)** )) &" )  GROUP BY F, G pivot O  ",1)),1,false))))
i can only assume i fell victim to a formula autocomplete inserting too many brackets.

Many thanks to those who took the time to have a look and give me some guidance